# Would a solderless breadboard be able to handle 20V without short circuiting?

Tags: power, circuit-design, dc, breadboard, stability

Until I can get a 12V power supply, I'm left with using a laptop charger as a power supply for my solderless breadboard.  Will the breadboard be able to handle it?

Comment: the breadboard would only get shortcircuited by the user plugging jumpers in the wrong place

Comment: Bear in mind that high-frequency AC (depending on your circuit) on a breadboard may lead to poor results, regardless of voltage.

Comment: Traditionally, analog circuits use +/- 9, 12 or 15 V for the power rails. So under low current consumption, a 18, 24, or 30 V potential difference is perfectly safe for solderless breadboards, and such voltages have been routinely used by many generations of EE students. But as other has mentioned, beware of the issue of the accidentally running high current across the breadboard.

Answer (score 12):

I've put 2000V on breadboards before, though with careful monitoring, current limiting, and avoiding nearby positions.  Possible they might even handle as much between adjacent positions... at least briefly.

There are many considerations that go into an insulation type rating, and the peak handling for short duration is only a small part of everything.  Still, it would be disturbing to find a breadboard that can't handle a few hundred volts between adjacent positions, and maybe a thousand or two for a short time.

20V is SELV (Safe Extremely Low Voltage), as defined by various standards e.g. IEC/UL 60950-1, and has a very low chance of causing breakdown of insulation (it doesn't "jump" as higher voltages can), and presents no shock hazard (as long as the power supply unit itself has reinforced type insulation, or the output is earthed).

Current rating is the higher priority here.  Breadboards have notoriously weak contacts, and are usually made of resistive materials like steel or nickel; I've ran 5A or so through mine, briefly, but they definitely get warm in the process, and loose (well worn) contacts won't handle that without sparking and intermittent connection.

You may want to use a current limiter -- even just a small series resistor, which also helps inrush current when plugging in large capacitors, or taking some of the load when you have an accident, like biasing a transistor wrong, or mistaken pinout, or short some wires/leads together, shorting out the supply.

Answer (score 8):

The safe limits will depend upon the quality of the solderless breadboard.

As an example, Multicomp specifies the voltage and current limits of their solderless breadboards as 300 V and 3 A.

A safe assumption is that the spring finger contacts have a resistance of 0.1 Ω to 1 Ω, and that the [ABS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acrylonitrile_butadiene_styrene) plastic will soften and then melt at around 2 A current, allowing adjacent buses to touch and short circuit. Depending upon the voltage and whether the short circuits cause an arc, the ABS plastic then may or may not catch on fire.

Comment: Bottom line: look at the published specification but only trust it if the supplier is in your jurisdiction and known to be reputable.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, yes. Should be no problem.

The weakest insulation on most breadboards is on the back, between the breadboard and whatever it's mounted on (if anything). This is often just a thin paper or plastic film that's stuck on to hold the metal contact strips in place. For best results, mount your breadboard on a plastic or wood surface. Then it should be good for at least 100 V or so.

Just like any component, a breadboard should have a datasheet. The datasheets that I've seen for breadboards usually have voltage and current limits of 200 V and 1 A.

Answer (score 3):

20 V is fine. Too much current can be an issue. The contact resistance is huge and can be 1 ohm. This means that the practical current limit is about 100 mA.

I highly recommend a lab power supply where you can limit the current to a reasonable amount. Your laptop power supply can probably put out 3 A, and it will probably shut down if there is a direct short, but a load that allows 3 A may be enough to damage the breadboard.

Comment: 1 ohm would be a really worn-out breadboard that should probably be tossed!